# In QML, how do I calculate the step size for a scroll bar such that the increase()/decrease() will only scroll to the next out-of-view item?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Pretty much included in the title.  I have a ListView of some graphic items (100 - 10000+ items depending on the list model) that have specific heights/widths.

As it is right now, pgUp and pgDn will skip too many items in the list.  How can I calculate the stepSize so that it will scroll to the next unseen item?

So far I've tried setting the index manually by calculating the number of entries in the view, which works somewhat, but it's not exactly the functionality I want.

I'm expecting it to be resizable, but always be able to pgUp/Dn to the next unseen entry.

Comment: you probably have to provide some [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentY` to implement `pgDn` and `pgUp` by incrementing or decrementing in pixel units. The `stepSize` is simply, the visible height of the `ListView`:

```js
    function pgDn() {
        listView.contentY += listView.height;
    }
    function pgUp() {
        listView.contentY -= listView.height;
    }
```

If you add bounds checking and updating the highlighted item, the above functions change to:

```js
    function pgDn() {
        listView.contentY = Math.min(listView.contentY + listView.height, listView.contentHeight - listView.height);
        listView.currentIndex = listView.indexAt(0, listView.contentY);
    }
    function pgUp() {
        listView.contentY = Math.max(listView.contentY - listView.height, 0);
        listView.currentIndex = listView.indexAt(0, listView.contentY);
    }
```

Here's a sample that creates 50 items of random height. `PgUp` and `PgDn` buttons are at the bottom that help navigates the `ListView` and change the selected item. The delegates are clickable which allows for manual selection as well as setting input focus so keyboard presses will work.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            height: h
            text: txt
            background: Rectangle {
                color: index & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
                border.color: "grey"
            }
            onClicked: {
                listView.currentIndex = index;
                listView.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        clip: true
        highlight: Rectangle {
            border.color: "red"
            color: "transparent"
            width: 2
            z: 2
        }
        Keys.onPressed: (event) => {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_PageUp) {
                pgUp();
                event.accepted = true;
            }
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_PageDown) {
                pgDn();
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "PgUp"
                onClicked: pgUp()
            }
            Button {
                text: "PgDn"
                onClicked: pgDn()
            }
        }
    }
    function populate() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            let txt = `Item ${i}`;
            let h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 40);
            listModel.append( {txt, h} );
        }
    }
    function pgDn() {
        listView.contentY = Math.min(listView.contentY + listView.height, listView.contentHeight - listView.height);
        listView.currentIndex = listView.indexAt(0, listView.contentY);
    }
    function pgUp() {
        listView.contentY = Math.max(listView.contentY - listView.height, 0);
        listView.currentIndex = listView.indexAt(0, listView.contentY);
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(populate)
}
```

You can [Try It Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAITXictVXbbtswDH3PVxDZMDhLZ7jD9uIsG9oGxYqlWNuhA/q0qjZjC1UkQ5ZzWZF/H2Unjm9ZCwzTQ0JRlHjIQ9J8niht4NpcZzx47PHa1j1T0mgl0qZ+ytYqM2nvikUITz2gNeWp+clxud3axUMfxFZdKpkMYqVTd8aF8CFhGqUpD+cqRFFcurRieUAyRsygDxcG55PtruLLriUPTeyXSNyF/cmV8A7eezXbGHkUGx/imtbginRmZWraBxY8RlplkuK5wcAwGYmmb7sCJZT2gcsQV/AGjuEL9F8hYh98EsIw7LeuPCgdona3N/uRxnXdaFPbKXkmKP9IQNrud6l2g0zbrF7kOMYFntFh85nSAZ4Ehi/wXAVZ6gxGByDspR8BlYU4ZdpdoDY8YMRaqeumpUFAoiiSdeWWeyKWbJ1+lx3uAsET4kVnWKpi4k8UHB7ipJFcjQ0CdgdGM5kWldjvRF5T/q4q9hC/4Tp1lbzSmKaWHwcX9N4Axp8bqPhse+Y+4hrGY2oqly7/sr10mww6iE2i26RJil3FKywIMDEYEtM2QYe4e871RC1lt/OJ/GfnhbQpB0Xe3B2TYt/0he1MKYNE0blm8yq7N2pZjKDuUiu4LFq/dn6aGaNkR5RF4/evKNPtJq10XUHFX1L8vIeJfMaDzfcL8jjLJPUs+UpUkgmahk6VPmpqcAQa4ESNN6K/T2P4aIXhsEmzNaOZR4b3drrC6ye+uR+1TGIyuGQmdmdCKe3kInVOqObk+S0cex4M4YPXqJWSVpclCcrQgSfydQTxBiqW3YHlqaiA3U84+i4Rw3c7RHMunfbhcH+hGPdHrRe+5nr6PDQsK9AOjdVSn8/XE+N47efvtu+0ArNV9KLA2KojsBbcI/D+C+IzRd99aXuJKpRkKgNbozQ2aOKLKRWddnblN+ht/gBTzznr)